# How do I prevent website user from seeing certain information until a certain condition is met.

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, web

So this is what I would like my website to do:

The website will generate a random number between 1 and 10,000.

The website user will then guess the number that the website generated by imputing their guess into a text-box.

If the user gets the number wrong a new number is generated and the user has to guess again.

If the user gets the number right a code-number is revealed.

My problem is that if the user simply inspects the java script they will be able to see the  code-number within the script. How do i prevent the website user from manipulating the javascript code to know which number the website generated? also, how do I prevent the user from accessing the code by looking at the javascript? Do i need to use php or something?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: store anything you don't want user to see on your server

Answer (score 1):

first of all you don't have to generate the number until they actually guess it.

```
function guess(number){
   var rand=Math.random()*10000;
   if(number==rand){
      //success
   }else{
      //failure
   }
}
```

This way no number is generated until they guess and you can't inspect that.

Also thinking outside the box: Based on the conditions, the number from the guess is irrelevant. If the number changes every time, they have a 1/10,000 chance every time to guess correctly. You simply have to write a function that only succeeds once every ten thousand times. However if they are looking at the source, they might feel betrayed by this.

Comment: Thank you, but i guess the point that  I was trying to make there was that the user could change the code if any way they like. They could change the random number generated to be between 1 and 2 instead of 1 and 10,000. Is there a way around this?

Comment: A debugger could assign a new value to `rand` after the initial declaration.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Yes there is absolutely no way around it and you have to use php. It's the exact same code logic though just different syntax.

Once you've done that though, don't forget they can spam your php file a million times to brute force their way to the right answer, so you have to put a block on that as well. I assume the prize for guessing the number is something important.

Comment: Technically `rand` should be converted to an integer to make the probability correct. But the answer is a good _illustration_ that the approach is wrong. The last time I timed out on Stack Overflow it gave me a set of images and requested I choose the ones with trees in them. Another time it might ask me to identify the cute kitten pictures.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answers guys. I figured this would be the case.

Comment: Is it possible to run PHP on a web hosting service?

Comment: Yes I can't imagine a web hosting service that wouldn't let you run php.

Answer (score 0):

If you put all your game logic on the client side, the client will be able to hack your game. All major web browsers come with a debugger which could easily manipulate and navigate your client side code in a variety of different ways.

That is why the server side should be responsible for these kinds of checks and validation.  If the client had to submit the number to your server, the answer could be generated on the server side where it would be safe from any tampering.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a lot of my concerns. Would implementing something like this in php be considerably more difficult than it would be to implement in java script?

Comment: It will be a little harder if you are not familiar with PHP, but all the fundamentals are the same.  Basically you just need to know how to pull parameters from the query string, how to randomly generate a number, and how to get the response back the page (JSON, Html?)